# File type for Slingshot/Dock Icons

Tags: icons

I'm writing a desktop entry file for a program that doesn't come with one. The icon the program has on Windows is a circle, but the one I found on the web has an annoying white square background. I'm trying to make a circle icon, but to do so I need a transparent background. I've tried using the .gif and .png file types, but they don't show up in the dock or Slingshot.
Is there a filetype that will keep the transparent background but still show up in the dock/Slingshot?

Comment: Welcome to  elementary OS SE, could you [edit] the question and add how & where did you install icon & desktop file. Could you add contents of desktop file. I would recommend svg icon, see why https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics#/media/File:Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg